# GCP alerting SMS charges

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-alerts

Does anyone know how Google charges on using GCP alerting SMS ?
Is it charged by the number of SMS/notification in GCP billing?
Is there's a threshold per GCP project?
How many phone numbers are we allow to set per  GCP project?

thank you.

Comment: so far i can only find the limits of alerts but still can't find price for SMS charges. https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quotas#alerting_uptime_limits

Comment: There are no costs associated with using alerting policies [link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts#limits)